# Image' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Drawing.Image' and 'iText.Layout.Element.Image'

Tags: c#, itext7

With that code I can split a multi tiff and save the images to files.

```
    public void SplitImage(string file)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(file);
        int count = bitmap.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);
        var new_files = file.Split("_");
        String new_file = new_files[new_files.Length - 1];
        for (int idx = 0; idx < count; idx++)
        {
            bitmap.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, idx);
            
            bitmap.Save($"C:\\temp\\{idx}-{new_file}", ImageFormat.Tiff);
        }
    }
```

here the code for the Pdf creation

```
    public void CreatePDFFromImages(string path_multi_tiff)
    {
        Image img = new Image(ImageDataFactory.Create(path_multi_tiff));
        var p = new Paragraph("Image").Add(img);

        var writer = new PdfWriter("C:\\temp\\test.pdf");
        var pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
        var document = new Document(pdf);
        document.Add(new Paragraph("Images"));
        document.Add(p);
        document.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Done !");
    }
```

now I would like to save the images to pdf pages and tried it with iText7. But this fails as

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using Image = iText.Layout.Element.Image;
```

are to close to have them both in the same class. How could I save the splitted images to PDF pages ? I would like to avoid saving first to files and reloading all the images.

Comment: Please could you post a [mcve]? Just having bits of the code doesn't really help us to help you. (Note that this isn't about `System.Drawing.Imaging` - `Image` and `Imaging` are different identifiers, and the C# compiler would certainly not object on the grounds that they're "close".)

Comment: You have a triple choice: You can add the full qualifications or you can add a `using` - alias (as suggested below) or you can separate the iText code form the GDI code into different cs files. This is what I would recommend for several reasons, code size being one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
using Image = iText.Layout.Element.Image;
```

is a so-called [using alias directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive). It creates the alias `Image` for the namespace or type `iText.Layout.Element.Image`. If this poses a problem, you can simply create a different alias. For example

```
using A = iText.Layout.Element.Image;
```

will create the alias `A` for the namespace or type `iText.Layout.Element.Image`.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe `iText.Layout.Element.Image` is a class, not a namespace. But I'm hoping the OP will post a complete example so that we can check what's going on more easily...

Comment: Jon, thanks for your comment. I think you are right; I will edit my answer.

Comment: I added already a second code snipped. It's actually enough to have the two code peaces in one class to get the ambiguous warning. Using the alias didn't work for me

Comment: actually that let me to a solution when explicitly using the System.Drawing.Image without another import

Comment: @user3732793: Instead of adding code snippets, it would be much more helpful if you've provide a single [mcve] as requested...

Comment: @JonSkeet understood. Will do better next time